# Group by latest date and update value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-update

I'm trying to write an sql query which:

- Gets customers which have multiple entries (by email) in the database and on the customer with the latest updated PasswordDate I want to update it's ID (pli.ID) to the email (pfd.TextValue).

I've written this query to retreive the users with the highest value on PasswordDate:

```
select pfd.TextValue as 'Email', MAX(pli.PasswordDate) as 'LastUpdatedPassword'
from [Customers].[PersonFieldData] pfd 
join (
    select pfd.TextValue from [Customers].[PersonFieldData] pfd
    where pfd.FieldDefinitionId = '_email'
    group by pfd.TextValue
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sub
on pfd.TextValue = sub.TextValue
join [Customers].[Person] p
on pfd.OwnerSystemId = p.SystemId
join [Security].[PasswordLoginInfo] pli
on pli.SystemId = p.SystemId
group by pfd.TextValue;
```

This is the query I've written to update these values (which does not work):

```
update pli
set pli.Id = pfd.TextValue
from [Jollyroom7].[Customers].[PersonFieldData] pfd 
join (
    select pfd.TextValue from [Customers].[PersonFieldData] pfd
    where pfd.FieldDefinitionId = '_email'
    group by pfd.TextValue
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sub
on pfd.TextValue = sub.TextValue
join [Customers].[Person] p
on pfd.OwnerSystemId = p.SystemId
join [Security].[PasswordLoginInfo] pli
on pli.SystemId = p.SystemId
```

I get the error message:
**Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'Security.PasswordLoginInfo' with unique index 'IX_PasswordLoginInfo_Id'**

How can I perform this update ONLY on the customer with the highest value on "PasswordDate"?

Comment: Updating an `Id` to a `textValue` sounds wrong to start with.

Comment: Well, sometimes you have to resort to something that doesn't sound great so solve a problem caused by something that was wrong to start with :)

Comment: I *assume* however, what you are after is an "updatable CTE".

Comment: Is this a one-off or a regular task?